# The derivative of a function raised to the nth power

Tags: functions, derivatives

I just started learning about derivatives and I am pretty familiar with almost all the concepts related to derivatives but there has been something that I yet have not fully mastered and that is finding the derivative of a function raised to the nth power where n is a rational number.
And also can you please show the proof?
P.S: I already know that the derivative of x raised to the nth power is n multiplied by x raised to the $(n-1)$th power.

Comment: Are you familiar with the chain rule? Do you know how to apply it?  Let $y = f(x)$ then $\frac {dy^n}{dx} = \frac {dy^n}{dy}\frac {dy}{dx} = ny^{n-1}y' = n(f(x))^{n-1}f'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the chain rule, $[(f(x))^n]'=n(f(x))^{n-1}f'(x)$. The chain rule is that $f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$, which is proved in any good calculus book